# Fetch disabled attribute options value using childnode of a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use class "myClass" from the below sample code and further store the values of option with "disabled" attributes in an array. i.e apple and orange value is needed.

```
<div class="myClass">
<ul><li></li></ul>  
<select>
<option value="">Choose an option</option>
<option value="apple" class="" disabled="">Red Fruit</option>
<option value="orange" class="" disabled="">Green Fruit</option>
<option value="mango" class="enabled">Yellow Fruit</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Note :There can be multiple instance of class "myClass" so probably would need to use a loop.

Something like :

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
for(var i=0;i<parent.length;i++){
    // Something here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled)  attribute does not need to have a value, so `disabled=""` could just be `disabled`. You could do it like this: Use `each()` to iterate through all elements with the class `myClass` and to iterate through all select options. Check if any of the select options is disabled by checking if they have the disabled attribute set.

```js
var disableds = [];
var parent = $('.myClass');
$(parent).each(function() {
  $(this).find("select option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("disabled")) {
      disableds.push($(this).attr("value"));
    }
  });
});
console.log(disableds);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <select>
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="apple" class="" disabled>Red Fruit</option>
    <option value="orange" class="" disabled>Green Fruit</option>
    <option value="mango" class="enabled">Yellow Fruit</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

If you would prefer to use javascript instead of jQuery:

```js
var disableds = [];
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
  var options = parent[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0].getElementsByTagName("option");
  for (var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
    if (options[j].hasAttribute("disabled")) {
      console.log("found");
      disableds.push(options[j].getAttribute("value"));
    }
  }
}
console.log(disableds);
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <select>
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="apple" class="" disabled>Red Fruit</option>
    <option value="orange" class="" disabled>Green Fruit</option>
    <option value="mango" class="enabled">Yellow Fruit</option>
  </select>

</div>
```